# Bluetooth headphones show as "not setup" and refuse to connect (22.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

My system has a dual boot setup, with Windows 10 as one OS and Ubuntu as the other. Switching between the two, I have realized that I basically need to remove my Bluetooth headphones as a device and reconnect them each time I switch from one to the other. Lately, my headphones have refused to connect to Ubuntu. Or rather, Ubuntu has refused to connect to them.

I haven't tried much yet, but when I click on the headphones in the Bluetooth settings tab to set them up, nothing is resolved.

Comment: have you tried removing the headphones in the Bluetooth setting and setting up them again? If it doesn't work, you can try blueman; it is in the apt repo. You can read it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/x11/blueman)

Answer (score 0):

I would not dual boot with Windows and Umbuntu.  People have reported problems when updates are downloaded.

I run a virtual machine or switch between external SSD drives.